# Cloudera VM Insufficient space for shared memory file

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, cloudera-quickstart-vm

I am getting below error while starting the Hive in cloudera VM CDH 5.10:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file: /tmp/hsperfdata_cloudera/26270 Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.

How to clear tmp drives or what are all the solution for this?